# Cakephp: Accessing a database table from view

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cakephp-2.0

I have the following code inside a view, but I'm trying to use a table instead of the array 'tags' to access the data for the autocomplete function. Can I do that because I read somewhere that the view should not interact with the model? If I can, can someone guide me how to? Please I need help! Thank you.

```html
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var tags = [
                "THE PAS",
                "THOMPSON",
                "TREHERNE",
                "VIRDEN",
    
               ];
    
    $( "#tagOrig" ).autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                            var matches = $.map(tags, function (tags) {
                                    if ( tags.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) === 0 ) {
                                            return tags;
                                    }
                            });
                            response(matches);
                    }
            });
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller should do it. Pick up the data from the model, set a variable and set it into the view. Or just use Ajax to fetch the data, while you render the view.